# body is hidden behind fixed nav

Tags: html, css

I want the fixednav div to butt up against the main div Ive tried to add a margin with % and that helps but I would have to use @media to adjust it as the browser shrinks.
Is there a way to get this with css only? and not use jscript

```css
#fixednav{
background-color:#00AFEA !important;
border: px solid blue;
min-height:100px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index:1;box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 0px BLACK;
}

.main {
border: px solid blue;
z-index:2;width: 100%;
margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixednav">
nav goes here and z index is 1 and the content is hidden as this div is covering it up

</div><!--fixed nav-->

<!--fixednav should rest against main not behind it-->



<div class="main">

    content goes here and z index is 2

   </div><!--main-->
```

Comment: no where near the same issue

Comment: @j08691 I believe that the problem the OP is facing is beyond an issue with the z-index.

Comment: can you be more clear? Do you want both divs stacked on top of each other? or do you want them to stick to each other side ways

Answer (score 0):

You need a position relative on the `.main` div.

> **Note**: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).
>
> — [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

```css
#fixednav{
background-color:#00AFEA !important;
border: px solid blue;
min-height:100px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
z-index:1;box-shadow: 0px 0.5px 0px BLACK;
}

.main {
position: relative;
border: px solid blue;
z-index:2;width: 100%;
margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="fixednav">
nav goes here and z index is 1 and the content is hidden as this div is covering it up

</div><!--fixed nav-->

<!--fixednav should rest against main not behind it-->



<div class="main">

    content goes here and z index is 2

   </div><!--main-->
```

Comment: @jamesgasrdner Okay, I think I understand what you're trying. Without JS or `@media` CSS tags, the only thing I can think of is to add a scrollbar to `.main`.